# How can I find an older version of pip that works with Python 2.7?

Tags: ubuntu, python, libraries, pip

I am using Ubuntu 20.10 in a Virtual Box. By default, this version of Ubuntu has Python 3.8 but I managed to install Python 2.7 (I need it for a specific program that does not work with Python 3) and to set it as default. Now, I need to install the wxPython library. If I am not wrong, I first need to install the pip package. However, I read that the newest version (pip 21.0) no longer supports Python 2. So, what can I do to install an older pip version that is compatible with Python 2.7 and that will allow me to obtain the wxPython library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing python2.7:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python2
```

Installing `pip`:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
sudo python2 get-pip.py
pip2 --version
```

To install `wxpython`:

```
pip2 install wxpython
```

or

```
python2 -m pip install wxpython
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked! While we are at it, could you kindly provide me a way to install and build the wxPython library for such an old version of Python?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, copy what Gad3r posted as input into the proper IDLE, interpreter, decompiler, scripting module, etc...

Installing Python2.7

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python2
Installing pip
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
sudo python2 get-pip.py
pip2 --version
```